# How to use the Dropbox Chooser on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOs

Tags: xamarin, dropbox

How can I integrate the Dropbox Chooser Api on a Xamarin Forms App for Android and iOs plataforms?
The documentation tell you how to do this on native Apps.

Comment: Yes, you have to create binding library from native library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create my own Nuget Plugin, since there is no one, search for "Plugin.DBChooser"
on the nuget gallery:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.DBChooser/

Here is the source of the plugin, Android/iOs Binding projects and the documentation, 
how to use the plugin in any Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOs projects:

https://github.com/LMachinery/Plugin.DBChooser

DropboxBind - iOs Binding project

DropboxChooserLib - Android Binding project

DBChooser - Plugin source code

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#ios) provided by Dropbox for their Chooser API, you have to use their Native SDK's on the iOS & Android platforms.

But since you are using Xamarin which is C#, you need to create a C# bindings library from the native libraries, if you can't find the those SDK's in the nuget packages manager. You are essentially entering the territory of Intermediate Xamarin Development- [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform/native-frameworks) & [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

There's many ways of doing it, and can take between 30 minutes to a 5 days to do. If you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/NyqxScrnJKw?t=3751) starting around 50:00, presented by the Lead of the Xamarin Components team, Jonathan Dick, you will learn one way of doing the entire binding process for iOS cocoa pods and android maven packages. But the Dropbox bindings process might be different.

Comment: Thanks, this seems not so easy, I will check If I can do that